# diagramming a poset of rectangles

Tags: analytic-geometry, order-theory, programming

Would it be feasible to program a computer to search for solutions to the following diagramming problem, say for up to $100$ rectangles?

Given a strict partial order on $n$ rectangles of fixed areas and variable dimensions, produce a Hasse diagram (within a reasonably-sized universe rectangle of fixed dimensions) subject to the following constraints:

(1) Every edge consists of one line segment whose endpoints lie on the perimeters of the rectangles it connects.

(2) Rectangle interiors do not intersect any edges or other rectangles and the only intersections allowed on perimeters are those described above.

(3) The rectangles are all parallel to the axes and precedence is compatible with bottom-side height.

Note that edges are allowed to intersect.

Comment: "fixed areas and variable dimensions" means what? And how does this "variable dimensions" relate to the "fixed dimensions" mentioned in the parenthetical. What is "bottom-side height" ("bottom side" would suggest a horizontal side, but "height" describes a vertical dimension)? And what does it mean for "Precedence" to be compatible with "bottom-side height"? And does "bottom-side" also indicate that all the rectangles must have horizontal and vertical sides?

Comment: The product of the dimensions of each rectangle is fixed (these products don't all have to be the same); the dimensions of the universe rectangle are fixed; we have $A<B$ if and only if the $y$-coordinate of the bottom side of $A$ is less than the $y$-coordinate of the bottom side of $B$.

Comment: Oh I guess I should have also mentioned that the rectangles must all be parallel with the axes---they're not allowed to be skewed.  Just added it.

Comment: I doubt it's feasible to program this for all but the first few $n$. Maybe not even $n=3$.

Comment: Perhaps the universe rectangle should be dropped, in which case the problem probably always has a solution and might be easy to program.  This simplified version wouldn't have much practical use though.  Yes, after a second's thought I can see that the problem is trivial without a bounding rectangle.

Comment: So you have rectangles $i = 1,\dots, n$, and are given the areas $A_i$ of the rectangles, and a partial ordering of them, and your task is to size and arrange them to fit within a larger rectangle and connect them in a Hasse diagram of the ordering?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I managed to slog my way through the impasse that prompted my question yesterday so it is just a theoretical one now.  The diagram Graphviz gave me is at https://mathematrucker.com/hasse_diagram_of_ellipses.png and my manually-constructed rectangle diagram is at https://mathematrucker.com/hasse_diagram_of_rectangles.png  Lots of light visible at the end of the tunnel now...it's very close to finished.  The rectangles contain info in the version that I will be using.  I find it far easier to read the rectangle diagram than the Graphviz one.

Comment: A key strategy is not letting the middle get too cluttered with rectangles.

Comment: Now that I understand the problem, I think I would assign min levels based on their longest paths to bottom, and max levels based on their longest paths to top. Assign a level between their min and max to each rectangle so as to make the sum of the areas on each level as close as possible to each other. Divide the total height by the number of levels, and drop the result a bit to leave room between the levels for edges to run. This will be the common height on each level. The widths are then obtained from the areas. Hopefully there is a little width left over for running edges between.

Comment: It is not optimal, of course - you can better by allowing some rectangles to extend over multiple levels. But it is a starting place for improvement.